# A creature that turns all water near it into slime

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, creature-design, chemistry, sea-creatures

I have an idea for a creature, and I want to figure out if it's possible. I'd rather not handwave it with "magic", so, here I am, asking the Stack.

The creature is eel-like, and is capable of emitting a chemical when scared that turns all water within a 5?( subject to change) into slime, rapidly (in around a few seconds). This traps predators, and it can escape by slipping through the slime.

Is this chemical possible? If so, can it be created through natural,biological processes? Also, can a slimy eel slip though the newly created high viscosity slime?

Comment: Have you looked at hagfish? They emit small amounts of proteins that turn into a stringy, persistent, gill-clogging slime: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bta18FdkVcA

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Hagfish should be the top answer to this question.

Comment: Now I feel less clever since you guys thought of hagfish hours ago but neither one bothered to post it.  Well, I am not proud.  HAGFISH RULE!

Comment: @Willk I thought it would be rude to post the answer before Christopher did.

Comment: @Daron - I have overcome such hesitations thanks to AlexP who routinely offers the germ of a fine answer in the comments.  Seminal ideas, as it were.  Then I come along and raise the baby and teach her kung fu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You have invented the hagfish.**

[image: hagfish]

https://www.livescience.com/57705-us-navy-synthetic-hagfish-slime.html

Hagfish are elongated eel-like (as regards body type) fish that make lots of slime.  I saw a video where one little hagfish turned all of the water in a bucket into slime.

https://www.thoughtco.com/hagfish-slime-4164617

> The Characteristics of Hagfish Slime When a hagfish feels threatened,
> it releases hagfish slime, a protein-based, jelly-like substance from
> slime pores that run the length of its body. The slime is a thick
> glycoprotein excretion called mucin, which is the primary substance in
> mucus, commonly referred to as snot or phlegm. Unlike other types of
> mucus, however, hagfish slime doesn’t dry out.
>
> The mucin is made up of long, thread-like fibers, similar to spider
> silk. These strands, which are arranged in bundles called skeins, are
> thinner than human hair, stronger than nylon, and extremely flexible.
> When the skeins come into contact with seawater, the glue holding them
> together dissolves, allowing the slime to expand rapidly. It is said
> that one hagfish can fill a five-gallon bucket with slime in only a
> few minutes. The slime fills the mouth and gills of the hagfish’s
> attacker, allowing the hagfish to escape.

The only problem with hagfish is that they are never used as school mascots.  I implore the WB community to address this terrible oversight.

Comment: Thank you! I thought something like this might exist, but I wasn't sure from where.

Answer (score 2):

Your creature would have to release a massive amount of substances in the water.

A glue like substance soluble in water is the basis, e.g.

**Polyvinyl acetate**

https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemical-engineering/polyvinyl-acetate

Then, in order to maintain the soft viscosity and reduce stickyness, add

- **Salt** or
- **Borax**

https://littlebinsforlittlehands.com/basic-slime-science-homemade-slime-for-kids/

https://www.independent.co.uk/life-style/slime-toys-poisonous-chemicals-boron-parents-warning-which-a8450666.html

How your creature would produce (or gather?) these substances, I don't know. But I think the amount of "excretion" needed will certainly limit the amount of water affected. The slime emitted would become a mantle around the creature, rather than extend far into the surrounding water.

It won't extend far. In order to affect all water around it, your beast would have to turn a relevant part of its own volume into slime.  Slime consists of 90% water, so there would be at least 10% of substance weight that would have to be released into the water.

*Note:* in Earth's nature, some animals release defensive substances into the water. Octopus can do that, blinding the attacker.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cephalopod_ink