# How could a human produce slime from his/her skin? Such as slime of a hagfish or slug?

Tags: science-based, super-powers

Would this slime be merely just mucus secreted out of pores? Also, should this be a passive ability (for instance always covered in slime) or should it be more of an activated one?

Comment: Hi @WilburWummins, there are quite a few slime questions already, that may provide answers. Have a look  at this recent one from Firedestroyer, https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/220588/a-creature-that-turns-all-water-near-it-into-slime

Comment: It takes only a little protein, but huge amounts of water to accomplish. If you want a bucket-full of slime, you start with a bucket-full of water needed, take that from a normal sized person and they die.

Comment: As for the last question, it may be easier if the slime cover would be permanent, that is always present. The slime could gradually build up.. like belly fat.

Comment: "Also, should this be a passive ability (for instance always covered in slime) or should it be more of an activated one?" Wouldn't this depend entirely on why you need slimy people in your story?

Answer (score 2):

**Humans make all kinds of glycoproteins.  Those make good slime.**

The inclusion of glycoproteins (e.g. [mucin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mucin), the mucusmaker) in bodily secretions alter viscosity and other properties.  Humans have a large array of glycoprotein containing secretions - for example, [we have 3 different kinds of saliva](http://www.vivo.colostate.edu/hbooks/pathphys/digestion/pregastric/salivary.html) each with different rheologic properties.  Some human secretions could be considered slimy.

Specific glycoproteins have been identified in milk, tears etc and some of these appear in sweat also.  They may have multiple roles but one role is to bind bacteria.

Secretions are made to modulate epithelial interfaces with the world and can be made more or less according to need.  In a circumstance where the skin needed extra protection that could be conferred by slime, you could have people who sweat slimy sweat.  Maybe it would be slightly hydrophobic like red hippo sweat.  Maybe it would be antibacterial, or protect skin from an environment with toxins - I think here of an environment with some ammonia as has been proposed here before.

Comment: +1 Q: agreed we can produce good slime already, but wouldn't it involve quite some changes, to let e.g. *saliva* be emanating from the skin ? We don't have the means of pushing a slimy fluid through pores in the skin.. to evaporate just water, no force is needed.

Comment: Check it out, @Goodies.  [Sweat glands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweat_gland#Mechanism) have contractile myoepithelial units to pump out that juice.